# using mysql_insert_id in mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysql-insert-id

I'm trying to put some data in db but something is going wrong.
This is my code:

```
 $insert = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO wp_users (ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name) VALUES ('NULL', 'teste', MD5('teste'), 'O Meu Nome', 'o_meu@email.com', 'http://www.o_meu_site.com/', '2011-06-15 00:00:00', '', '0', 'O Meu Nome');
    ");

    $insert2 = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (NULL, '" . mysql_insert_id() . "', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";b:1;}');
    ");

    $insert3 = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (NULL, '" . mysql_insert_id() . "', 'wp_user_level', '10');
    ");

    ?>
```

The problem is:
The last INSERT is using mysql_insert_id() is not using the ID from the first query, it using umeta_id.
What i need to change?
Please help

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @njk: Hah is that a canned response?  I believe I've seen the same text a few other times today...

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Not sure who the original author is, but you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/3881905).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first insert statement , you have null embedded in single quote . It will be a string value

Answer (score 1):

```
 $insert = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO wp_users (ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name) VALUES (NULL, 'teste', MD5('teste'), 'O Meu Nome', 'o_meu@email.com', 'http://www.o_meu_site.com/', '2011-06-15 00:00:00', '', '0', 'O Meu Nome');
    ");

$insertId = mysql_insert_id();

$insert2 = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
       VALUES (NULL, '" . $insertId . "', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";b:1;}');
");

$insert3 = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
       VALUES (NULL, '" . $insertId . "', 'wp_user_level', '10');
");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress).

While the other answers work, you should really used the [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object and not `mysql_query()` directly.

Specifically:

- [`wpdb->insert()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)
- `wpdb->insert_id`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the returned value in a variable since `mysql_insert_id()` will always use the ID from the last `INSERT` statement.

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_users (ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name) VALUES ('NULL', 'teste', MD5('teste'), 'O Meu Nome', 'o_meu@email.com', 'http://www.o_meu_site.com/', '2011-06-15 00:00:00', '', '0', 'O Meu Nome');
");
$id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (NULL, '" . $id . "', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";b:1;}');
");

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (NULL, '" . $id . "', 'wp_user_level', '10');
");
```